# Defining type of variable as number does not throw error even if value is string --TypeScript, Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I just started looking into angular and type script. I am trying to restrict the execution of function if the parameter passed is not of type number but it is failing. Can anybody help me in this or if i am missing anything. Thanks.

/**TS File **/

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  txtVal: number;

  getval(val:number){
    console.log('val', this.txtVal)
  }
}
```

/*HTML*/

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]= "txtVal">
<button (click)="getval(txtVal)">Get Val</button>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d9hwsi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Types in TypeScript are a compile time concept. Once the program is running, you are in JavaScript world.

Comment: @Henry so we cannot write function the way I have written

Comment: Errors would be caught if you tried to call your function from inside the component class. But since you are calling it from HTML, there is probably no type checking there. By the way, I recommend you type it as `number` instead of `Number`.

Comment: @Frank ModicaI - I have tried type it as number too its giving same result.

Comment: @MritunJay frank mean that you should use the type number in lowercase because the primitive type in Typescript is in lowercase if you use as Capitalized form Typescript will think it's a Class or Interface

Comment: @PhelipeRocha got u.. but I tried in lower case too its not restricting the function from executing.

Comment: @MritunJay yeah, typescript can't do that, because of typescript work only for lint propose while de developer is coding. For this behavior you need to make a function like in the answer from Vlad274

Comment: @MritunJay check your typescript code here http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ so you can understand better how typescript work. You can see that after typescript compile to javascript it doesn't create any type cheker

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, type definitions in TypeScript are a compile-time check. This compile-time check is only effective for .ts code, thus the Angular binding is not validated for types.

If you wish to restrict the execution at runtime, you need to do it manually

```
getval(val:Number){
  if (typeof val !== "number") {
     throw new Error("Value is not a number");
  }

  console.log('val', this.txtVal)
}
```

Alternatively, if you just want to log the error and not mess with the execution

```
getval(val:Number){
  if (typeof val !== "number") {
     console.error("Value is not a number");
     return;
  }

  console.log('val', this.txtVal)
}
```

---

However, since you're passing the value from an input field you likely want to test if the value the user has entered can be converted to a number.

```
getval(val: string){
  const numberValue = Number(val);
  if (numberValue === Number.NaN) {
     throw new Error("Value is not a number");
  }

  // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: down voted because he is getting the value from html input tag which is having tag binding as text.

Comment: @VaibhavKumarGoyal A fair point, that I've addressed in an update. I like your method of restricting the input with `type` attribute as well

Answer (score -1):

Edited your [stackbiltz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3tcaap).Please change your binding from the html itself as

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]= "txtVal">
<button (click)="getval(txtVal)">Get Val</button>
```

then if you use typeOf it will return you the type as number

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import{Observable} from 'rxjs';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  txtVal :any;
  tet: number;



     getval(val :number){
    if(Number.isNaN(parseInt(this.txtVal)))
    {
      return;
    }
    else{
        console.log('couldn\'t convert' );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: same solution was given by one of the user but he got downvoted. Dont know why

Comment: @MritunJay that is absolute you can work with as anything coming from html is interpreted in angular according to the dom object property type ,so set your input tag as text it'll end up throwing back everything as string

Comment: input tag as text it'll end up throwing back everything as string but my method is expecting parameter as number. then it should prevent the method from executing.

Comment: @MritunJay kindly visit the stack biltz edit to see it working